# Как в django выбрать все записи в таблице на которые ссылаются с другой таблицы и объеденить их

Tags: sql, django

Желательно одним запросом

Например: (пример выдуманный, интересна реализация)

```
class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField('Автор', max_length=100)
    publicated = models.DateTimeField('Создан', auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

class Fantactic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=100)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
```

Сделать что-то вроде этого

```
1. select * books left join fantastic on books.id = fantastic.book_id where author='Rich';
```

или (тоже желательно)

```
2. select * books left join fantastic on books.id = fantastic.book_id where title='Sunrise';
```

Точнее мне надо получить все поля (книги и жанра), 'Автор, Дата публикации, Название' где Id книги равно book_id в Жанре. И при этом Название было "Sunrise" или автором был 'Rich'

Book.objects.filter(fantastic__title="Sunrise") не помогает. Он выведет только Автора и дату публикации. А название не выведет.

Т.е `SELECT author, publicated FROM book INNER JOIN fantastic on book.id = fantastic.book_id where fantastic.title = "Sunrise"`

А нужно `SELECT * FROM book INNER JOIN fantastic on book.id = fantastic.book_id where fantastic.title = "Sunrise"`

или

`SELECT author, publicated, title FROM book INNER JOIN fantastic on book.id = fantastic.book_id where fantastic.title = "Sunrise"`

Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете django, зачем вы пишете собственные SQL запросы там где для этого предназначен фреймворк?

`Fantastic.objects.filter(book__author="Rich")`
`Book.objects.filter(fantastic__title="Sunrise")`

Так же советую сначала прочитать про [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) там все очень детально расписано.

**UPD после редакции вопроса:** 
Если проблема только в том, что якобы *нет* поля тайтл — то оно *есть*.

К нему можно обращаться через `b.fantastic__title` где `b` — конкретный экземпляр коллекции книг.

Comment: Так я и спрашиваю, как на фреймворке сделать.

Comment: У вас в два запроса получается. Нужно что-то вроде этого Book.objects.filter(book__title="Sunrise") и Book.objects.filter(book__author="Rich"). Не зависеть от модели Fantactic или других моделей

Comment: И нужен именно SELECT *. В ответе получится только поля Books или Fantastic

Comment: У вас тоже два запроса. Пишите понятнее, что вы в итоге хотите получить (опишите словами — например: все книги которые <…>). Да и пример у вас крайне странный: `title` – это аттрибут книги, никак не жанра.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.